# What is the subject in the sentence

Tags: grammar, verb-agreement

What is the subject in the sentence," My shoes have been repaired."

Comment: This sentence is written in the passive voice. You may want to look up what passive voice construction is and how it works. If you do this, the subject of the sentence should be immediately obvious to you.

Answer (score 1):

"My shoes" is the subject in this sentence. 
For more info read https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/academic_writing/active_and_passive_voice/more_about_passive_voice.html
Hope it helps!